# Error in QuantLib-Python when I use function "Bond"

Tags: programming, quantlib

I am using the "Bond" function in QuantLib-Python 1.14.

I am planning to use it in this way:

```
BondPtr::BondPtr(Natural,Calendar const &,Date const &,Leg const &)
```

I tried to construct the last parameter as `ql.Leg((cf1,cf2,cf3,cf4))`

where `cf1=ql.SimpleCashFlow(3,ql.Date(25,1,20XX))`, `cf2=...`, `cf3=...`, `cf4=...`

Finally, I got the error:

```
RuntimeError: no coupons provided
```

Can someone one tell me how to make it correct? Thank you a lot!

Here is my code for reference:

`import QuantLib as ql
cf1=ql.SimpleCashFlow(3,ql.Date(25,1,2019))
cf2=ql.SimpleCashFlow(3,ql.Date(25,1,2020))
cf3=ql.SimpleCashFlow(53,ql.Date(25,1,2021))
cf4=ql.SimpleCashFlow(51.5,ql.Date(25,1,2022))
couponsLeg=ql.Leg()
couponsLeg.push_back(cf1)
couponsLeg.push_back(cf2)
couponsLeg.push_back(cf3)
couponsLeg.push_back(cf4)
newBond=ql.Bond(0,ql.UnitedStates(),ql.Date(25,1,2018),couponsLeg)`

Comment: My purpose is to construct a bond with advanced principle payment (I have added my code for reference).
I have read the C++ code, I am not clear whether I used the ql.Leg() correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Bond` constructor expects a leg of coupons and you are giving it a leg of simple cashflows.

You can build it like this (the redemptions will be assumed from the coupons):

```
dc = ql.Thirty360()
cf1 = ql.FixedRateCoupon(ql.Date(25,1,2019), 100, 0.03, dc, ql.Date(25,1,2018), ql.Date(25,1,2019))
cf2 = ql.FixedRateCoupon(ql.Date(25,1,2020), 100, 0.03, dc, ql.Date(25,1,2019), ql.Date(25,1,2020))
cf3 = ql.FixedRateCoupon(ql.Date(25,1,2021), 100, 0.03, dc, ql.Date(25,1,2020), ql.Date(25,1,2021))
cf4 = ql.FixedRateCoupon(ql.Date(25,1,2022), 50, 0.03, dc, ql.Date(25,1,2021), ql.Date(25,1,2022))
couponsLeg = ql.Leg([cf1, cf2, cf3, cf4])
newBond=ql.Bond(0,ql.UnitedStates(),ql.Date(25,1,2018),couponsLeg)
```

Or, better yet, you can simply use the `AmortizingFixedRateBond` class:

```
notionals = [100,100,100,50]
schedule = ql.MakeSchedule(ql.Date(25,1,2018), ql.Date(25,1,2022), ql.Period('1y'))
bond = ql.AmortizingFixedRateBond(0, notionals, schedule, [0.03], ql.Thirty360())
```

Both would output the same cashflows, which I believe is what you want:

January 25th, 2019 3.0
January 25th, 2020 3.0
January 25th, 2021 3.0
January 25th, 2021 50.0
January 25th, 2022 1.5
January 25th, 2022 50.0